# Disable webpack from injecting CSS / Autoprefixer not working

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-style-loader

New to webpack but currently webpack is injecting styles into my document body which I would like to disable.  I am not sure how to accomplish this.

Here is my webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    entry: {
        app: './js/app.js'
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({use:[{loader: 'css-loader', options: {importLoaders: 1}}, 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader']})
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css'),
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({options: {
            context: __dirname,
            postcss: [
                autoprefixer
            ]
        }})
    ]
};
```

The html output is

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/wp-content/themes/index/styles.css">
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
            background-color: black; }

            h1 {
                color: #fff; }

            p {
                display: flex;
                color: #fff; }
       </style>
       <style type="text/css"></style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <p>Test</p>
        <script src="/wp-content/themes/index/dist/bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see it is still inject css that doesn't match the scss file I have.  It is also not prefixing the the flex property or including an import I have in my sass file.

main.scss

```
@import 'test';

body {
    background-color: black;
}

h1 {
    color: #fff;
}

p {
    display: flex;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: red;
}
```

_test.scss

```
h2 {
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Euuuh... you have only one loader, which is an scss loader... what are you exactly expecting?

Answer (score 1):

There are three problems that need to be addressed with your configuration.

First, the `loaders` property inside `module` should be renamed to `rules`. The way you have it now was the correct way for webpack 1, webpack 2+ uses `rules`. https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#module-loaders-is-now-module-rules

Second, `LoaderOptionsPlugin` was used to migrate from webpack 1 to webpack 2. You can read about it [here](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/loader-options-plugin/).

The new recommended way to attach options to `postcss-loader` looks like this.

```
{
   loader: 'postcss-loader',
   options: {
       plugins: [autoprefixer()]
   }
}
```

With the above configuration in place, your css should be prefixed and you can safely remove `webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin` from your `plugins` array.

Finally, if the information you provided above is correct, `_test.scss` is not being included in the final bundle because in `main.scss` you have

```
@import 'test';
```

Change it to import `_test` and you should see it included in the bundle.